# Applying multiple middlewares on routes laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created three custom middleware namely `RedirectIfNotAdmin`, `RedirectIfNotStartup`, `RedirectIfNotInvestor`.

**Middleware code Respectively:**

```
class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user()->user_type;
        if ($user != 'admin') {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}  


class RedirectIfNotStartup
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user()->user_type;
        if ($user != 'startup') {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}


class RedirectIfNotInvestor
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user()->user_type;
        if ($user != 'investor') {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'UserControllers'), function(){
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin', 'startup', 'investor']], function () {
        Route::any('showidea/{id}', ['as' => 'showidea', 'uses' => 'IdeaController@showIdea']);
        Route::get('community',  'UserController@showCommunity');
        Route::post('communities', 'UserController@addCommunity');
        Route::get('edit/{id}', ['as' => 'edit', 'uses' => 'UserController@editCommunity']);
        Route::get('delete/{id}', 'UserController@deleteCommunity');
        Route::post('update/{id}', ['as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'UserController@updateCommunity']);
        Route::any('create', 'IdeaController@displayPost');
        Route::post('idea', 'IdeaController@storePost');
        Route::get('users', 'UserController@showUserListing');
        Route::get('deleteUser/{id}', 'UserController@deleteUser');
        Route::get('delete/idea/{id}', 'IdeaController@deleteIdea');
        Route::get('approve/{id}', 'IdeaController@approveIdea');
        Route::get('edit/idea/{id}', [ 'as' => 'edit/idea', 'uses' => 'IdeaController@editIdea']);
        Route::post('update/idea/{id}', [ 'as' => 'update/idea', 'uses' => 'IdeaController@updateIdea']);
    });
});
```

The problem i am facing is that, it is only going into `RedirectIfNotAdmin` middleware and not in other two `middlewares`. It should authorize routes which are made for `startup` and `investor. But it is applying`admin`middleware on every route and returns the response`unauthorized`

**Kernel file:**

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
      'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
      'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
      'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
      'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
      'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
      'investor' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotInvestor::class,
      'startup' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotStartup::class
   ];
}
```

Comment: Once you return a Redirect, the next middlewares won't obviously be applied.

Comment: You need to change the order of the middleware, so it will be ['auth', 'startup', 'investor', 'admin']

Comment: I changed the order and now it is thrwoing `fatal error`
>     Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Auth' not found @Robin Dirksen

Comment: What should i do now @Arcesilas

Comment: It seems like it is unable to find both `investor` and `startup` middleware

Comment: add: `use Auth;`at the top of your middleware file to solve that fatal error

Comment: Still same issue. it goes into just one middleware `RedirectIfNotAdmin` and make all the routes `unauthorized` for other type of users also. @Christophvh

Comment: Problem is not in order, it's in you logic, as an eample if someone is admin he/she not going to pass startup or investor middlwares, so you alaways get unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

Try using middleware group and since those middleware are identical, use one middleware instead of separate them, something like:

```
class RedirectIfNotUserType
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $type = null)
    {
        $user = Auth::user()->user_type;
        $type = explode('|', $type);

        if (! in_array($user, $type)) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In your `Kernel.php` register your middleware and create a new group:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    ...

    'type' => [
        'auth',
        'type:admin|investor|startup',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...

   'type' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotUserType::class,
];
```

And use `type` middleware on your `routes.php`

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'UserControllers'), function(){
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'type'], function () {
        ...
    });
});
```